# Java array_name[0].length function bug?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
char[][] board = {
            {'#','#','#','-','@','-','#','#','#'},
            {'#','#','-','@','@','@','-','#','#'},
            {'#','-','@','@','-','@','@','-','#'},
            {'-','@','@','@','@','@','@','@','-'}};

System.out.println(String.format("Rows: %o, Columns: %o", board.length, board[0].length));
```

For some reason, Java outputs 11 columns. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `%d`, not `%o`. `%o` will present the result in Octal. 11 in Octal is 9 in Decimal.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I need a refresh on format specifiers